# Listas de dicionarios

Tags: python-2.7

Eu tenho uma lista de dicionários como a seguinte e pretendo obter para uma lista as idades das animais de cada dono, por exemplo , o animais da ana tem em media x anos ... No entanto não estou a conseguir obter as idades dos animais relacionadas com os respetivos donos, alguem pode dar uma ajuda ?

```
lista1 =[
{'Idade': '8','Especie': 'Gato', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
{'Idade': '57','Especie': 'Tartaruga','Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
{'Idade': '12','Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
{'Idade': '2','Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'},
{'Idade': '45','Especie': 'Tartaruga','Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
{'Idade': '9','Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Milo'},
{'Idade': '57','Especie': 'Tartaruga','Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
{'Idade': '4','Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'}]

lista2 =[
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana','Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva','Nome do Animal': 'Dory'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ada','Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplan'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana','Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva','Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana','Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva','Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'}]`
```

O problema é que eu não posso usar input's nem nada disso e o código tem de funcionar para uma lista qualquer a que pus em cima é apenas um exemplo.O que eu tenho de obter ( neste exemplo) é :

```
[{'Ana':'53','Eva':'5','Ada':'12'}]
```

Mas primeiro preciso de juntar as idades dos animais de cada dono numa lista para depois fazer  a média que é isso que não estou a conseguir. E em relação ao espaço tinha razão obrigado, já retirei.

Comment: Você duplicou essa pergunta aqui? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124946/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-one-dictionaries-list-depending-on-information-from-an

Answer (score 0):

Na lista2 o primeiro os primeiros campos `Nome do Dono` possui espaço, isso pode atrapalhar na hora da consulta.

Tente usar esse trecho de código

```
item = int(input("Numero da pessoa: "))

animal = lista2[item-1]['Nome do Animal']

for x in range(len(lista1)):
    if animal in lista1[x]['Nome do Animal']:
        print "Idade:", lista1[x]['Idade']
        print "Especie:", lista1[x]['Especie']
        print "Nome:", lista1[x]['Nome do Animal']
        print "Dono:", lista2[item]['Nome do Dono']
```